# Problem in exporting a dataframe to csv format in R

Tags: r

I have got a result file (data frame) which I tried to export in csv format using:

```
write.csv (x = as.data.frame(data_1), file = "result.csv")
```

where data frame looks like:

```
    Name    estimate    std.error   statistic   p.value Note    
4181    A1  0.0856767524298681  0.0126892271621709  6.7519283353432 1.33883410848243e-10    protein 
7424    A2  0.0369509779463753  0.00547265553056216 6.75192833534319    1.33883410848245e-10    protein 
27359   A3  0.0323211629170586  0.00478695289875522 6.75192833534319    1.33883410848246e-10    protein     
28332   A4  0.00213432164701004 0.000316105494757381    6.75192833534319    1.33883410848246e-10    protein 
1051    A5  0.010932202013597   0.00161912293357321 6.75192833534319    1.33883410848247e-10    transposon  
4385    A6  0.0147964405980457  0.00219143922493864 6.75192833534319    1.33883410848247e-10    protein     
15123   A7  0.0135530291636489  0.00200728273324601 6.75192833534319    1.33883410848247e-10    protein     
261     A8  0.0480231071967026  0.00793221999921915 6.05418246108026    6.21446623962322e-09    Cytochrome  
4145    A91 0.0241010500508526  0.00398228634177247 6.05206355907736    6.28471539629882e-09    protein designed based on radioactive probe
```

It got exported and when I tried to open it in excel, all the data shows in one column without any delimiter. I can fix each file at a time by saving again in new format but I think there might be a better fix at the exporting step in R. Thank you!

Comment: Please show a little bit of `data_1`, something like `dput(head(data_1))`

Comment: Nothing looks wrong here. It looks like `data_1` is already a data frame, so your `as.data.frame()` shouldn't be necessary---but it shouldn't hurt either. Could you perhaps open up the saved CSV file in a normal text editor (like RStudio) and make sure it looks like comma separated values?

Comment: You can try to import it with excel. Either use text-import or rename the file as ".txt" and import it with excel. Therefore it should give you some kind of import settings and preview...

Answer (score 0):

Since csv file use comma as the delimiter.
Try adding `sep = ","`.

```r
write.csv (x = as.data.frame(data_1), file = "result.csv", sep=",")
```

Comment: `sep = ","` is the default for `write.csv`.